# Redirect API calls

Tags: node.js, express, gulp

I'm building a gulp task which starts an express server. To get the site to work I need to redirect requests from locahost to a certain IP.

This is what I have right now:

```
var rewrite = require("connect-url-rewrite");
gulp.task('express', function() {
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var rules = [
        "^localhost\/(.*)$ 192.168.1.1\/$1"
    ];;

    app.use(require('connect-livereload')({
        port: 35729
    }));

    app.get('api/v1', function(req, res, next) {
        res.redirect('http://192.168.1.1:8090'+req.originalUrl);
    });

    app.use(rewrite(rules));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));

    app.listen(8090);
});
```

When I make a request to localhost:8090/api I want a redirect to 192.168.1.1:8090/api.

How can I rewrite the hostname? The only thing I get to work is rewriting the pathname.

**Update:**

When I add an redirect the request gets canceled. How can I pass all headers to my res object?

Comment: That rewrite middleware [rewrites `req.url`](https://github.com/loopj/connect-url-rewrite/blob/a2861c4849bbfd8c50edf77259caa877f4ad642a/lib/index.js#L14) which only contains the pathname. I think you will need to use `res.redirect`.

Comment: Is the request you're talking about some AJAX stuff? If so the request is canceled because it would be a cross-origin request. What is it that you're trying to accomplish? Is your question eg. "How can I proxy AJAX calls to backend with Gulp when developing frontend on localhost"?

Comment: Yes this is exactly my question.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use http://www.charlesproxy.com/. But let me know if you have an idea how to fix this with gulp

Answer (score 1):

One easy way for proxying the AJAX calls to your backend with Gulp would be to use [gulp-webserver](https://github.com/schickling/gulp-webserver). Example:

```
var gulp      = require('gulp'),
    webserver = require('gulp-webserver');

gulp.task('server', function() {
  gulp.src('./public')
    .pipe(webserver({
      port:       8090,
      livereload: true,
      proxies: [
        {
          source: '/api',
          target: 'http://192.168.1.1:8090/api'
        }
      ]
    }));
});
```

This will proxy all routes under `/api`, ie. call to `http://localhost:8090/api/v1/users/1` would proxy the request to `http://192.168.1.1:8090/api/v1/users/1`.

`./public` in the example is the root folder for the static assets the web server serves, ie. the folder to which you copy the compiled asset files in your Gulpfile.